# PHP's include() function not working xampp

Tags: php, html

Please bear with with me as I am new to web dev. I am attempting to use the include function in php to display a header on a web page.

I am using two very simple files, placed in the same directory and am using XAMPP.

*index.php*

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>

    <?php 
    include('header.php');
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

*header.php*

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

When I open index.php, the statements from header.php never show up. All I see is one "Hello", as printed in index.php.

I have attempted to follow many tutorials online similar to this (ex https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp, https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-include-files.php), but none of them work for me.

Please let me know if you have any advice.

Comment: Is the `header.php` in the same folder?

Comment: @biesior "I am using two very simple files, placed in the same directory and am using XAMPP."

Comment: that simple code *should* work - just tested it locally and it shows *'properly'*. However I'd suggest to go with some little bit more advanced templating system, pure including files just becoming non-comfortable sooner than later

Comment: Thanks for testing it on your own machine. Do you know of any reasons why this code wouldn't work on mine? I looked into if I might be referencing the file path incorrectly, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: If you view the page source is the PHP code there?

Comment: Yes it is @user3783243. The first <html> tag and the php code are highlighted in red, which I believe means a syntax error

Comment: Are you requesting with `file://` or `http://`? Sounds like you aren't going through the web server which bypasses PHP processing

Comment: I think that may be the problem @user3783243. Thank you for your input. I just have one last question, sorry it's a little basic. How do I change the index.html / index.php file that opens when I go to localhost?

Comment: Do you mean if you load `http://localhost/`? If so https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex should control which resource is served

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons you should use the following statements instead of `include`, unless you have a good reason to not do so:

Either

```
require_once 'header.php';
```

or

```
require 'header.php';
```

This will cause an **E_ERROR** in case the file was not found or you don't have permissions to include it. Otherwise you run into the risk not executing code which is mandatory for your program.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried both require_once and require, however index.php still does not appear as it should. How do I access the error log to see if it threw either of those errors?

Comment: Can you open the HTML source code and have directly a look into it? You should see - at least if you use `require` - an error message. You can try to post the resulting HTML source code into your question.

Comment: I don't see an error in my IDE (VSCode) or when inspecting the page in a web browser. I'm not sure if I am looking in the correct place however.

Comment: Your PHP code may be not executed at all. In XAMPP you would view the page using your webbrowser by typing http://127.0.0.1 into the browser or so.